# Does Cramer's condition imply strong mixing?

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, dependent-variable, tail-bound

In Theorem 1.4 of [D. Bosq](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0387985905/?coliid=I1J1QY9Z5PA3B2&colid=3PKFP0BGISQBG&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) the Cramer's condition is a prerequisite for the tail bound of sum of dependent variables. The Theorem is as follows:

> Let $(X_t,t\in\mathbb{Z})$ be a zero-mean real-valued process. Suppose that there exists $c>0$ such that
> \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}\lvert X\rvert^k\leq c^{k-2}k!\mathbb{E}X_t^2<+\infty,\quad t=1,\cdots,n,\quad k=3,4,\cdots 
> \end{equation}
> then for each $n\geq 2$ each integer $q\in\left[1,\frac{n}{2}\right]$, each $\epsilon>0$ and each $k\geq 3$
> \begin{equation}
> P\left[\Bigg\lvert\sum_{t=1}^n X_t\Bigg\rvert>n\epsilon\right]\leq a_1\exp\left(-\frac{q\epsilon^2}{25m_2^2+5c\epsilon}\right)+a_2(k)\alpha\left(\left[\frac{n}{q+1}\right]\right)^{\frac{2k}{2k+1}}
> \end{equation}

where $a_1,a_2(k),m_2$ are constants that have been defined in the book and $\alpha\left(\frac{n}{q+1}\right)$ is the $\alpha$-mixing operator, - i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\alpha\left(\left[\frac{n}{q+1}\right]\right)=\sup_t\alpha\left(\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^{t},\mathcal{F}_{t+(n/q+1)}^{+\infty}\right)
\end{equation}

Now if I assume that a process $X_t$ is strong mixing, would I still have to make the Cramer's assumption as well? Or would strong mixing implies the Cramer's condition?